# Excel drop down list not working in other cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

What I'm trying to do is make a drop down menu using a name range and data validation.
Simple enough however the problem arises when I have multiple cells running off the same name range.

In my spreadsheet I have two rows using two different name ranges.  The problem is occuring for both.  One line is employee names and one line is project manager names.

The following link is an image of the cells in question.  I do not have 10 rep and as such cannot post an image sorry.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WcYb.jpg

The first cell is normal and the drop down works fine however, the adjacent cell which is a copy of the first cell doesn't drop down anything.

the code I'm using to define the range for my drop down is:

```
=MANAGEMENT_list!$D$2:INDEX(MANAGEMENT_list!D:D,LOOKUP(2,1/(MANAGEMENT_list!D:D<>""),ROW(MANAGEMENT_list!D:D)))
```

The range goes from D2 to the last nonempty cell in column D.

When I do data validation for the other cells I  get "the source Currently evaluates to an error".

Hopefully I've included enough information if not feel free to ask and I will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to lock your ranges since you are copying to the right:

From

`=MANAGEMENT_list!$D$2:INDEX(MANAGEMENT_list!D:D,LOOKUP(2,1/(MANAGEMENT_list!D:D<>""),ROW(MANAGEMENT_list!D:D)))`

To

`=MANAGEMENT_list!$D$2:INDEX(MANAGEMENT_list!$D:$D,LOOKUP(2,1/(MANAGEMENT_list!$D:$D<>""),ROW(MANAGEMENT_list!$D:$D)))`

Comment: This did the trick, I'm new to excel and VBA sorry if my question was really remedial.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @impactblu no problem. Glad to help. Can you please mark my question as the one that resolved your issue?

Comment: This is not VBA. It's a formula. :-))